# Periodic JavaFX Service

Tags: java, javafx-2

I am wanting to execute a task at a regular interval from my JavaFX application. The task pulls data from a remote stream.

While I know I could use a Timer as suggested below:

[JavaFX periodic background task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9966136/javafx-periodic-background-task)

I believe this should be able to be done using the JavaFX [Service](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Service.html) object. There's mention in the Javadoc about specifying a custom executor ([ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html) comes to mind here), but how would one specify the period and delay? Ideally, this would use the Service's usual start, reset, restart, and state bindings...

```
public class MyFirstLineService extends Service<String> {
     private StringProperty url = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "url");
     public final void setUrl(String value) { url.set(value); }
     public final String getUrl() { return url.get(); }
     public final StringProperty urlProperty() { return url; }

     public MyFirstLineService() {
         setExecutor(new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor());
     }

     protected Task createTask() {
         final String _url = getUrl();
         return new Task<String>() {
             protected String call() throws Exception {
                 URL u = new URL(_url);
                 BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                         new InputStreamReader(u.openStream()));
                 String result = in.readLine();
                 in.close();
                 return result;
             }
         };
     }
 }
```

Comment: Seems like forcing yourself to use the Service class is making things more complex.  Is there anything that service offers that you need that ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor does not offer?

Comment: Have to agree with Andy Till here, why use a `Service` in the first place? And if you're certain that is what you want, wouldn't it be a better alternative to have a `Timer` restart the `Service` periodically?

Comment: The Service object can directly interact with the FX Application Thread. Complexity added by trying to implement a ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor saves complexity in creating proxy objects for moving data in and out of the service (i.e. stream parameters from TextField controls, stream output to TextField controls). I certainly can do the executor using a proxy object, but thought this would work better.

sarcan - I tried using a timer to restart the service, and am getting an exception because the restart happens off the FX Application Thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A ScheduledService was requested in the [JavaFX issue tracker - RT18702](http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-18702).

The tracker includes [source for a preliminary implementation](http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/secure/attachment/27545/ScheduledService.java) which has not been incorporated in the 2.2 branch.  If needed, you could take a look at that source and see if it helps improve on your solution.

Comment: Neither this answer nor mine actually answered the question. But this definitely seems like the most appropriate solution.

Answer (score 2):

I have found a way to do this, building on the comments from sarcan above...

One can create a Timeline object, normally used to animate UI elements, as a timer that operates on the FX Application Thread. Using this its possible to restart the Service object, which then performs the long-running operation on a background thread, yet preserves property access and updates via the FX Application Thread bindings.

Ex:

```
    final MyFirstLineService svc = new MyFirstLineService();
    final Duration oneFrameAmt = Duration.seconds(5);
    final KeyFrame oneFrame = new KeyFrame(oneFrameAmt,
            new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent evt) {
                    svc.restart();
                }
            });
    Timeline timer = TimelineBuilder.create()
                            .cycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE)
                            .keyFrames(oneFrame)
                            .build();
    timer.playFromStart();
```

Answer (score 1):

Run into the same problem. An example with `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` could be:

```
ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);

Service s = new Service(){
    @Override
    protected Task<String> createTask() {
        return new Task<String>() {
            @Override
            protected String call() throws Exception {
                // code...  
            }
        };
    }
}

// created tasks shall be run in thread pool
s.setExecutor(executor);

// start the service the first time
s.start();

// restart the service every 5 seconds
s.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // need runLater here since trigger needs to be in the javaFX thread
            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    checker.restart();
                }
            });
        }
    }, 0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

Could be solved with a `Timer` but then you lost the JavaFX data binding capability (as you already mentioned). Looking forward to Java8!