# How to create service for connection check

Tags: javafx-2, javafx, javafx-8

For JavaFX 8 application I want to create service which checks network status. Can you tell me how I can create very light service which runs every 5 seconds and performs some action?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`ScheduledService`](http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/concurrent/ScheduledService.html) in JavaFX 8 which can help you define a periodic task in the background. It is in fact a [`Task`](http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) factory that creates a `Task` at each interval on which you can define a callback on the GUI Thread.

See also [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18816603/periodically-refresh-data/18825444#18825444) where I have put an example of `ScheduledService`.

In your case, you can use any popular Java library to test the network (Apache http components for instance to test HTTP) on your `Task` defined in your `ScheduledService`.

Comment: Just check if you can connect to the Google website. If you can then set a flag that you are connected else dont.