# JavaFX Timeline: app freezes for a while after pressing the button

Tags: java, concurrency, javafx

I have a button that activates communication with the server. Every minute some data is taken from remote server. But when I click on the button my app freezes for several seconds, even if I use Timeline.

```
private Timeline timer;

@Override
public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    //Data initialization like read textfields' content

    view.getConnectButton().setText("Reconnect");

    setCounters();

    if(timer != null) {
        timer.stop();
    }
    initTimer();
    timer.play();
}

private void setCounters() {
    String dataFromServer = model.getCybergameViwers(); //Retrieve data from server
    //make something with received data
}

/**
 * Updates counters every 60 seconds
 */
private void initTimer() {
    timer = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(60), new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            setCounters();
        }
    }));
    timer.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
}
```

According to this, timer runs in background and sends request to the server every minute. But after the first and further button press, app freezes. I suspect `setCounters()` in the `handle()`, but without it, fields initialization will take place in 60 seconds.

How to fix app freeze on first button press?

Answer (score 0):

Your server call is in your JavaFX Application Thread not in a background Thread, it is just a periodic call inside the Application Thread.

When setCounters() is called, your server is dealing the request so if it takes time, it locks your UI.

If you want a periodic task in a background thread with probably a callback in the Application Thread, you should look at ScheduledService that is provided with JavaFX 8, you can take its implementation in your code if you want to stay on JavaFX 2 too.

There is a question that is similar to yours: [Periodically refresh data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18816603/periodically-refresh-data/18825444#18825444)

Comment: Isn't it too complicated for one launch before Timeline "comes to the scene"?

Comment: @Dragon setCounters() must not be called from your Application Thread if you don't want to freeze UI. To define the first call to your server instead of calling it in your FXML listener handle() you can use a Task within a Service to do the job for instance and then use a ScheduleService with callback for periodic update. It is concurrent programming and yes it is a bit complicated, still I don't see a simpler way to achieve that.

Comment: I think it is better to run handle in a separate thread. I found that I also connect to DB and this also can cause "freezing". And if it runs in a separate Thread (and timer runs in it too), I'll get rid of freezing.

Answer (score 0):

It waits until a response comes. Use separate thread to call this function and you wont face this problem